# How to slide a pattern brush along a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, brush

I created a pattern brush and applied to a path. I'd like to slide it through that path but can't find a way to do it.

I have a workaround for when it's on a straight line but I can't seem to find a solution for other situations.

For example, I made this shape to create a Thorn Vine pattern brush:

[image: Pattern base]

When I create a pattern brush, it works really well, as you can see here:

[image: Pattern Brush on straight path]

If I want to slide the pattern along a straight path, I can just make it longer and then expand and cut the part I want, like so:

[image: Cropping to simulate pattern sliding]

I can even fake it for circles:

[image: Faking pattern sliding with circles]

But how should I do it if I have a closed path? Like a rectangle, triangle, ellipse, star or even a custom path?

[image: Actual problem I'm facing]

It seems ridiculous to make a pattern brush for every "offset" I want. All "solutions" I have are bad because, even though they work, it involves a lot of work. Imagine having to extend the start and end of a open path just to have this??? Yikes. And even though, those solutions don't work at all for closed paths. The ideal would be to have a "slide" or "offset" inside the brush settings but that currently doesn't exist. Or at least I can't find. Does someone know if I'm missing something or have a tip for how could I achieve this?

Using a scatter brush doesn't work because the patterns don't connect with each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, no, there's no way to "slide" or "offset" the pattern starting point on the path.

One possible workaround would be something like this:

1. Cut the path with the knife tool [image]
   [image]
2. Delete extra point, this moves the starting point to the spot where you cut the path.
3. Join the points and now you have a closed path again, with the starting point that's shifted.
   [image]

Comment: Oh, okay. This will work for now. Thank you so much for the suggestion! I'll also submit a feature request to Adobe's team. Maybe someday solving this issue will be as easy as changing a value somewhere.